# Capture OLE-C# exception from java eclipse-rcp application

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, ole

I've written a c# OLE and I've integrated inside my java eclipse-rcp application throgh the class OleAutomation of org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32 described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-ActivexSupportInSwt/index.html)

Is it possible to throw exceptions from the OLE and catpure them with a try/catch statement inside the rcp application?

Many Thanks